# How do I convert back to UTC given a time without timezone and the current user's timezone in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I am storing dates as UTC in the database, and I want to present a date-time to the user, which they can then edit.  Upon storing this date-time, it needs to be converted back into UTC.  When displayed to the user, no timezone information is given.

What I need is an "inverse" of .in_time_zone, such as .from_time.zone.

What is the best practice for converting a datetime without timezone, along with a known timezone, into a UTC date-time (timestamp)?

Answer (score 0):

[`utc()`](http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/utc)

Adjusts DateTime to UTC by adding its offset value; offset is set to 0

```
datetime = DateTime.now
 => Thu, 03 May 2012 00:34:42 +0300
datetime_utc = datetime.utc
 => Wed, 02 May 2012 21:34:42 +0000
datetime_utc.in_time_zone('Minsk').to_datetime
 => Thu, 03 May 2012 00:34:42 +0300
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't clarify.  I have a time, without zone, and i need to convert it to a time WITH zone, ie i need to SET the time_zone of a Date object.

Comment: But you can't store time in `Date` object, just a date.